# Calculation in Kivy with inputs from several widgets (and output to a different one)

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to build an app with kivy that asks for some numbers and then returns a calculation, but I need the input numbers to be provided on different widgets. I've been searching for a way to do that, and it seems that it can be done with ObjectProperty() or NumericProperty(), but I can't figure the correct way. For a barebone example (not working, obviously), below is the code for an app where two numbers are introduced and it calculates the sum. The main.py is

```
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

    class SumRoot(BoxLayout):
        pass

    class FirstInput(BoxLayout):
        pass

    class SecondInput(BoxLayout):
        pass

    class OutputSlide(BoxLayout):
        def sum_of_inputs(self):
            self.resultado.text = str(float(self.first_input.text)+float(self.second_input.text))

    class SumApp(App):
        pass

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        SumApp().run()
```

and the sum.kv files is

```
    SumRoot:

    <SumRoot>:
        carousel: carousel
        first_slide: first_slide
        second_slide: second_slide
        third_slide: third_slide

        Carousel:
            id: carousel
            FirstInput:
                id: first_slide
            SecondInput:
                id: second_slide
            OutputSlide:
                id: third_slide

    <FirstInput>:
        orientation: "vertical"
        first: first_input
        TextInput:
            id: first_input
        Button:
            text: "Next"
            on_release: app.root.carousel.load_slide(app.root.second_slide)

    <SecondInput>:
        orientation: "vertical"
        second: second_input
        TextInput:
            id: second_input
        Button:
            text: "Sum"
            on_press: root.sum_of_inputs()
            on_release: app.root.carousel.load_slide(app.root.third_slide)

    <OutputSlide>:
        orientation: "vertical"
        result: result_output
        Label:
            id: result_output
```

The intended behavior is that when one presses the "sum" button it calculates the sum, goes to the next slide and displays the sum. All suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Pass references of the inputs to the `OutputSlide`, which does calculations:

```
OutputSlide:
    id: third_slide
    first_input: first_slide.first
    second_input: second_slide.second
```

2) Add object properties in *py* file, which will hold them:

```
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
...
class OutputSlide(BoxLayout):

    first_input = ObjectProperty()
    second_input = ObjectProperty()
    result = ObjectProperty()  # this one aswell, don't leave bare ids
```

3) Calculate the result `on_press` correctly:

```
<SecondInput>:
....
on_press: app.root.third_slide.sum_of_inputs()
```

Additionally, fix naming bugs in `OutputScreen`.